# Laravel API not reflecting changes made directly in database

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am having trouble with my API written with Laravel. Basically, I modify a value directly in the database used with Laravel, but it seems to get the original value(s) not the one that has been modified.

At first I thought maybe it could be cache related, but we aren't using any cache drivers. Other than the cache drivers, is there some sort of magic caching Laravel is doing behind the scenes? Is this normal behaviour for laravel apps?

Is there something else I need to clear each time I modify a value directly in the database?

If I were to modify this value via the API itself, then I am given the correct modified value.

Thank you!

Comment: Where exactly are you accessing the data here?

Comment: Maybe the changes are not actually being saved? It would be easier to determine the problem if you included the code that saves and retrieves data from the database.

Comment: What happens if you do a `$model->refresh();` before you retrieve an API? Also don't forget that the browser itself has a internal cache. Which means you'll have to resend the value of the collection back to the API. You don't provide us with any code, so it's not easy to help you out.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?